# Dividing a string with list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to get a list of a string:

```
string = "A1B3C3D4"

list = ["A1","B2","C3","D4"]
```

What is a pythonic way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: post code or we can't help

Comment: The pattern you want to extract is not clear from the example. Do you want every pair of characters or could something like AB123 could appear in your list?

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all non-overlapping matches of pattern `[A-Z]\d` in a given string.

```
import re

regex = r"[A-Z]\d"
string = "A1B3C3D4"
result = re.findall(regex, string)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['A1', 'B3', 'C3', 'D4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this example:

```
word = 'CatBatSatFatOr'

print([word[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(word), 3)])

Output:
['Cat', 'Bat', 'Sat', 'Fat', 'Or']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **re.findall** in your list coprehension:

```
import re

lst = [x for x in re.findall(r"[A-Z]\d", string)]
```

after execution of above code you will get:

```
lst = ['A1', 'B3', 'C3', 'D4']
```

Comment: `re.findall` itself returns a list. why make a new list out of the same list?

Comment: You're right, just based on the question, I used python list comprehension syntax. @VishalSingh

Comment: **pythonic** doesn't mean do things using a list comprehension.

Comment: @VishalSingh no, but the title of OPs question does